# Schedule cron job every midnight for every timezone with Meteor

Tags: meteor, cron, timezone

I need to run a cron job every midnight for every timezone. What is is the best way to accomplish this with Meteor?

There are some packages that deal with cron jobs + timezone, but not for every timezone dynamically.

For example: In this CRM, every day it will set specific actions for users for the next day, but i can only set the tasks when the work day is over, otherwise it will break things.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just schedule a cron job for every half hour and then only go after the documents in the matching tz (if any). You need every half-hour because there are some tzs that are offset by 30min, ex: India).

Comment: There are several that are 45 min offset also...

Comment: @MichelFloyd, In my DB I've saved user timezone as string from moment e.gl `America/New_York`. How to find out which in which timezones it is midnight now? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[vsivsi:meteor-job-collection](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection) is a Meteor package which helps running jobs and schedule them. It provides hook for [Later.js](https://bunkat.github.io/later/index.html) which has an awesome API to schedule tasks.

Figure out the logic how you want your jobs to run and you can implement using them.